# Trigger-like boolean

Tags: c#

I would like to create custom boolean struct which is acts like a trigger, in details if I set it to true, it will be true only at the first "check", after it became false.

I've just created quickly a class to simulate, what I would like to achieve, for better understand.

Is it possible? Thank you.

```
public class Trigger
{
    private bool trigger;
    private bool trigger_ctrl;

    public void Set(bool value)
    {
        this.trigger = value;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        this.trigger_ctrl = false;
    }

    public bool IsTriggered()
    {
        if (!this.trigger)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (this.trigger_ctrl)
        {
            return false;
        }
        this.trigger_ctrl = true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to set it to false after it's read?

Comment: Are you asking if you can set `Trigger` instance to a variable/property that is defined as `bool` and still have it trigger when that `bool` gets set to a `true` or `false`? No, you cannot do that. The variable/property would have to be declared as `Trigger` from the start in order to handle being set from a `bool`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyTrigger
{
    private bool _trigger;

    public bool Trigger
    {
        get 
        { 
            var val = _trigger;
            _trigger = false;
            return val;
        }
        set { _trigger = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. That's exactly what I was going to post.